# when i normally run html bootstrap enabled code, it shows proper output but when i load it using codeigniter view it shows different output

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

This is my directory:

```
miuse/application  
miuse/application/views/templates/header.php    
miuse/bootstrap/css  
miuse/bootstrap/js  
miuse/bootstrap/fonts
```

This is my controller code:

```
<?php
    class page extends CI_controller{
        public function view($page= 'home')
        {
            if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
                show_404();
            }
                $data['title']='Moodlist home';
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            }
    }
?>
```

This is my view code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
    <?php echo $title; ?>
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<header class="container">
<div class="row">
<h1 class="col-sm-4">List</h1>
        <nav class="col-sm-8 text-right">
            <p>Home</p>
            <p>Category</p>
            <p>About us</p>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run my view normally in a browser it shows proper output but when i load it with codeigniter view then it shows different output which i dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `header.css` file is not being loaded.

Put the `header.css` file in `miuse/bootstrap/css` directory.

And change your code from,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css" type="text/css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/miuse/bootstrap/header.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: optimus prime, my header.css file was inside application/views/templates directory. i tried to run it from there itself by just changing the code to: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/miuse/application/views/templates/header.css" type="text/css">       but it did not work

Comment: No, it won't work like that, keep css and js files in a separate folder, outside application. The folder containing files can be in same directory as application. Glad this helped. If your problem is solved, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

When loading css and other stuff I would recommend using base_url() in your head area

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/header.css');?>">
</head>
```

Make sure you have set the base url in config.php and autoload the url helper.